# merge two models in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm currently training a ner model using stanford ner. Is it possible to merge two models together? or is there a way to expend current model?

Suppose I originally have a large corpus called A, and I get a model MA. (Which works good)
But the problem is, it takes long time to train it and in the future I want to add entries into corpus A, say, B. I have to retrain (A + B) again which takes longer time.

Is there a way to just train B and merge it with A? Or I can.. expend the model MA to make it work for new entities.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "general way". It depends on the models you are using, some of them can be trained in **online mode** (where new instancs, new data do not require retraining) while some cannot. So on this level of generality the answer to your question is **no, you cannot, you need to retrain it each time**. On the other hand, some of the models can be trained this way - look for those which support **online learning**.